# How to cache an AWS S3 file on a node.js server and serve it on request?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, ember.js, amazon-s3, ember-cli

For my website, I am deploying all the `assets` (fonts/images/js etc) to an `S3 bucket`. The `index.html` (a single-page Ember.js application), is deployed on an elastic beanstalk `node.js` server. The node `app.js` takes any request to `www.domain.com/*` and serves the locally stored `index.html`. I would like to be able to cut out the process of deploying a new application to elastic beanstalk for every production build and simply deploy all assets and the `index.html` to the `S3 bucket`.

This is what I have so far:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk'),
    fs = require('fs');
/*
 * AWS Security credentials
 */
AWS.config.loadFromPath('./config.json');

var port = process.env.PORT || 3000,
    http = require("http");

var static = require('node-static');


/*
* Create a node-static server instance
* to serve the './public' folder
*/
var file = new static.Server();

/*
 * Fetch .index.html from S3
 * and cache it locally
 */
var s3 = new AWS.S3();
var params = {Bucket: 'assets', Key: 'index.html'};
var file = fs.createWriteStream('index.html');

s3.getObject(params).
    on('httpData', function(chunk) { file.write(chunk); }).
    on('httpDone', function() { file.end(); }).
    send();

var server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    request.addListener('end', function () {
        file.serveFile('index.html', 200, {}, request, response);
    }).resume();
}).listen(port);
```

This I assume will only get the `index.html` from S3 when the server first fires up. What would be the best practice for caching, preferably with a 1 minute expiry.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at Amazon's CloudFront. Sounds familiar for what you're trying to accomplish, namely that the files wouldn't have to go through your server again. Adds a little to the round-trip of your full page load.

That said, to cache locally, you could store the entire file in `Redis` (or other quick thing like that, `Raik`, `memcache`, etc.).

1. Run Redis on your server
2. store file into Redis when pulled from S3
3. Set expiratory time after saving to Redis
4. Check Redis for custom key before re-pulling from S3

   - If it exists, use it and reset the timeout
   - If not, repull from S3 (storing in Redis and setting timeout)

I am unsure how this would respond if the files were large, but it would still be faster than pulling from S3 each time.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Redis or any of these, could you give an example code on how to implement this? Sorry I'm very new to node.js!

Comment: In that case, I would suggest just deploying everything, each time, to elastic beanstalk. Or at least break your project into two pieces - server side and frontend side. Until you are familiar with your system and have a fully working "thing", don't worry about optimizing just yet.

Comment: I've managed to get redis set up now. I follow this tutorial https://medium.com/@feifanw/framework-agnostic-fast-zero-downtime-javascript-app-deployment-df40cf105622

I can get the latest index.html key and therefore the latest file. Have you got a clean suggestions for serving the received html file?

Comment: That is sounding like a new question, so search around, but you would serve the file with whatever is your http framework (ExpressJS, Restify, Connect, etc.). You would serve the file in the http `response` variable - the actual command would depend on your http framework.

Comment: Hey, I managed to get it to work with express, aws-sdk and redis for node. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad you got it working, I hope it works the way you need it to. Mark as answer if that applies.